# How to Bypassing the certificate validation for tibco EMS .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, tibco-ems

I am trying to connect with tibco server using ssl (ssl://host:port) but we required to bypass certificate verification.

In Java There are one API available such as

```
System.setProperty(BaseClient.TIBCO_STATSVCS_SSL_ALLOW_ANY_CERTIFICATE, "true");
```

We required same functionality in .Net API.

Comment: Hi Mahadik, did my answer solve your problem? If yes, could you please mark it as correct? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Edit:
By changing the ServerCertificateValidationCallback you change the logic with which certificate are accepted (return true) or not (return false)
This code simply skips the certificates validation: any certificate will be accepted

You can of course add more logic.

You need to create your own handler, which is a method with the same inputs/output as the delegate definition:

```
public delegate bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors);
```

So, for example:

```
 public static bool MyCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
   //whatever
 }
 public static void Main() {
     System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyCertificateValidationCallback;
 }
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if you need more details